# nginx location contains string + end with

Tags: regex, nginx, location

How to match for location in Nginx:

- contains /render/framed/
- ends with .php

I tried `location ~ /render/framed/ {` just for contains "/render/framed/" and it works.
But couldn't find how to specify, must end with .php

Tried: `location ~ /render/framed/+\.php$ {`

Is it possible?

Comment: Try `/render/framed/.*\.php` instead of `/render/framed/+\.php$`

Comment: @Sergio Unfortunately not working `location ~ /render/framed/.*\.php {`

Comment: Actually, `location ~ /render/framed/.*\.php$ {` should work (mind the `$` anchor). Probably, you may need to use double quotes, `location ~ "/render/framed/.*\.php$" {`, not sure though. Also, try replacing `~` with `~*` for case insensitive matching.

Comment: Yes, should be working but it's not because it's a 404 response `error_page 404 = /url_rewriting.php;` and `location` does not work for 404 response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search tells me that NGINX uses the good old PCRE regexp flavor. So is this what you want -

Sometext /render/framed/ .php - Should match

Sometext /render/framed/ .txt - Should not match

Then the below pattern should work. If it does not, can you give some test strings and the desired output.

```
.*(?:\/render\/framed).*(?:.php)$
```